# Apelidar colunas com valor retornado de Select

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando renomear coluna de SELECT com o valor retornado de um outro SELECT.

Ex:

```
SELECT ID, NOME, QUANTIDADE AS QTDE_4 FROM TESTE
```

Onde em QTDE_4, o 4 seria o mes atual. Tentei colocar o valor da consulta separado em uma variável, porém sem sucesso também.

A minha query estava ficando assim:

```
SELECT ID, NOME, QUANTIDADE AS CONCAT(`QTD_`, '', SELECT MONTH(NOW()) ) FROM TESTE
```

O banco que estou utilizando é o MYSQL. Se alguém souber como ajudar, pls comenta ai.

Comment: Pra que você quer fazer isso?

Comment: Cara se você colocar o nome da coluna dinâmico no SELECT como você vai fazer pra pegá-la no result set?

Comment: Alias é uma constante. Para criar os aliases dinamicamente, você terá que montar a sua query como uma string para depois executá-la. Mas, qual é o seu propósito real? A sua query de exemplo não justifica essa abordagem.

Comment: A ideia era cruzar com outra tabela e pegar a quantidade de transações que ocorreram nos 3 ultimos meses, porém para saber de que meses essas transações eram, queria renomear a coluna com cada mes.

Comment: É besteira fazer assim, se você colocar um exemplo dos dados das suas tabelas como exemplo e estrutura delas e mostrar o resultado **final** que você quer podemos sugerir soluções mais pontuais para o seu problema

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @sql varchar(300) 

select @nome = 'QTD_' + cast ( MONTH(getdate()) as varchar) 

print @nome 

select @sql = 'select id, nome ' + @nome + ' from bot_arquivo '

print @sql

exec(@sql)
```

Confesso não ver motivo para essa utilização apesar do cenário que você comentou.
Aconselho rever se essa solução é realmente a melhor forma de utilização do SQL.